# What can shut down a websocket connection?

Tags: python, websocket

I use [`websocket_server`](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server) in order to provide a one way (server to client) websocket connection.

I have several threads on the server which query at given intervals (`while True: ... time.sleep(60)`) an API and then perform a `server.send_message()` call to update the client. All of this works fine.

From time to time, without any particular reason, I get a crash:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:/Dropbox/dev/domotique/webserver.py", line 266, in calendar
    server.send_message(client, json.dumps({"calendar": events}))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\websocket_server\websocket_server.py", line 71, in send_message
    self._unicast_(client, msg)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\websocket_server\websocket_server.py", line 119, in _unicast_
    to_client['handler'].send_message(msg)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\websocket_server\websocket_server.py", line 194, in send_message
    self.send_text(message)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\websocket_server\websocket_server.py", line 240, in send_text
    self.request.send(header + payload)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 10058] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call
```

There is no shutdown call in my code. **What else can shut a websocket down?**

Comment: I am wondering, is the server object that you created, thread safe?

Comment: @SRC: this is a good point, I did not think about that (and I do not know whether it is)

Comment: I suggest you look around for this a little bit. Looks to me that it can very well be a case of that. I may be wrong as I have very little experience in the particular lib you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebSocket client can ask the server to close the connection (or directly close it). From [the library's code](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server/blob/4370d05d72444baab079c59e752ded63d4e08553/websocket_server/websocket_server.py#L173-L180):

```
if not b1:
    logger.info("Client closed connection.")
    self.keep_alive = 0
    return
if opcode == CLOSE_CONN:
    logger.info("Client asked to close connection.")
    self.keep_alive = 0
    return
```

You could check `self.keep_alive` to know if the socket is still open.

Comment: Ha. I missed that message in the logs (it is not enriched and was lost in mine which are longer and structured). Indeed I now see at some point `Client asked to close connection.` in between calls (without anything special happening). Would you know how a client (a browser), on its own (ie. not via my code) can request a websocket to be closed? I understand that this is something I could request in my JS code but this is not the case.

Comment: When the browser is closed, the network connection is reset, ... You should assume a WebSocket can be broken at any time and have a way to recover its state when the browser reconnects.

Comment: In my case the browser (Chrome) is open and waiting for data to come in (after some time (and some updates from the server)) it closes the connection. I could adapt the server to recover when the client reconnects - the thing is that it (the client) disconnects and does not reconnect. I will follow your idea and add some `alert()` on the client triggered upon disconnection (though there should be none)